# Orthogonal trajectory of $ xy = 2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find orthogonal trajectory of $xy = 2$ hyperbola.

Differentiating wrt x:

$$x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y = 0$$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-y}{x} \ \ \ \ \ ... (1) \ \ \ \ \ \ \\=\dfrac{-2}{x^2}\ \ \ \ \ ...(2)$$

Now we replace $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ with $\dfrac{-dx}{dy}$ and solve.

<strike>The problem is that eqn (1) gives wrong curve but eqn  (2) gives correct curve.</strike>

**Edit:**
From **1** and **2**  here we get two **different** answers. Are they both correct?

Comment: You substituted $xy=2$ to get from (1) to (2), but that relation isn't true on the orthogonal curve.

Comment: Let's see if form a different point of view. Consider $xy=3$. Isn't that a different curve than yours? Now diff we get $x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y = 0$ which is....the same as your derivative. But when we substitute $y=3/x$ we get the correct curve for my example. Similarly when you substitute $y=2/x$ for your example you get the right curve.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Actually 2 gives correct ans! and answer of 1 is wrong!

Comment: @imranfat I see what you said, but whats really going on?

Comment: @samjoe What is going on is that all curves $xy=c$ have the same derivative which is $x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y = 0$. So how can answer 1) in the post be correct for all? That's why substituting the original function back is needed, hence 2) is right as you indicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "give the correct ans".  So I'll solve both equations:

(1) If $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y}{x}$, then the orthogonal trajectory satisfies $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y}$.  So
$$
    x \,dx = y\, dy \implies \frac{1}{2} x^2 = \frac{1}{2} y^2 + K
$$
for some constant $K$.  Renaming the constant $k=2K$, we see the orthogonal trajectories have equation $x^2-y^2 = k$.

(2) If $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{2}{x^2}$, then the orthogonal curve has equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2}{2}$.  Then $y = \frac{x^3}{6}+C$.

As long as $xy=2$ and $y = x^{3}/6 +C$ intersect at some point $(a,b)$, then their tangents are orthogonal.  But we usually talk about orthogonal *families* of curves.  For *any* point $(a,b)$ in the plane, there is a curve of the form $xy=c$ through it, *and* a curve of the form $x^2-y^2 = k$ through it, and those two curves have orthogonal tangents at $(a,b)$.  This is the stronger result, and what I would call the expected answer.

Comment: Sorry I earlier failed to understand what you said! Thank you! Btw shouldn't both the curves be called orthogonal curves to original curve as both of the cut it at 90 deg?